# I have created a Sharepoint list in 2013 with Expiry date and email ID. The requirement is auto mail has to be generated

Tags: list, email, sharepoint-2013

I have created a SharePoint list in 2013 with Expiry date and email ID. The requirement is auto mail has to be generated to with number of item which is going to expire.

Answer (score 0):

Create workflow using SP Designer or VS.